# How do I interpret these results for a Proportion Test in R?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

```
> prop.test(table(D2$SMOKE,D2$RACE),correct=FALSE)

2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  table(D2$SMOKE, D2$RACE)
X-squared = 23.26, df = 1, p-value = 1.415e-06
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1863890 0.3809326

sample estimates:
   prop 1: 0.7733333   
   prop 2:  0.4896725
```

Comment: what is your hypothesis? How do you compute proportions ?  IS there any logic to use chi- square statistic for your study ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prop1` and `prop2` are the probabilities of success for your 2 groups. the `p-value` is less than one minus the level (95% or 0.95) of the confidence interval, which indicates the proportions of the characteristic studied are statistically significantly different in the 2 groups.

maybe you can have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-proportions-z-test-in-r) which show a complete example of such test.

Comment: Generally, we also ignore the $\chi^2$ (`X-squared`) value and the `df` (degrees of freedom) since the confidence interval contains all the information we need. We can also conclude that the proportion difference is statistically significantly different because the confidence interval does not contain 0 (indicating no proportion difference).

Comment: It is incorrect to use chi-square test for the stated purpose . Moreover, question does not indicate sample -sizes and requisite classification tables or data that could be useful for suggesting an apprpriate test - t or z  etc.